# Column values to single string observation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Trying to group by Product variable and concatenate values from column into string

df:

```
Product    Value

 TV         0.1
 TV         0.2
 TV         0.15
 DVD        0.001
 DVD        0.01
 Netflix    0.1
 Netflix    0.2
 Netflix    0.25
```

I want to create a DF in the form:

```
Product    Value
 TV        (0.1, 0.2, 0.15)
 DVD       (0.001, 0.01)
 Netflix   (0.1, 0.2, 0.25)
```

I thought I should be able to use something like:

```
 df['Value'] = df.groupby('Product')['Amount'].apply(",".join(map(str, df['Value])))
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. I have tried without the *map()* to no avail. I think I am probably over complicating this but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: `df.groupby('Product')['Value'].apply(tuple)` ?

Comment: Hi, using .apply(tuple) seems to be putting every value in each product group. i.e the values from TV, DVD and Netflix are in each of the rows.

Comment: In other words, the grouping doesn't seem to be working

Comment: can you add an example how this doesnt work. for clarity

Comment: I am getting a result which looks like (0.1, 0.2, 0.15)(0.001, 0.01)(0.1, 0.2, 0.025)

Comment: thats exactly what you said you wanted? do you mean `df.groupby('Product')['Value'].apply(tuple).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, just apply the lambda such that:

```
df.groupby('Product')['Value'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(map(str, x)))
```

and you get the desired result.

If the open/close parenthesis are crucial simply add:

```
df['Value'].apply(lambda x: f"({x})")
```